# Is it possible to rewrite/proxy POST requests in Netlify?

Tags: netlify, netlify-cms

Netlify noob here.

I'm currently migrating an old Ruby on Rails app to use Netlify for a static site. There are some legacy static pages that we want to keep on our old code base, and these legacy static pages make POST requests to our server.

It seems like redirects for POST requests aren't possible (see the [W3 documentation for 301/302 redirects](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)- `If the 301 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued.`), but I was wondering if this is different when you proxy/rewrite the URL.

Currently, we rewrite a user's request to `www.domain.com/legacy_slug` via Netlify's splat redirect (similar to what the author of [this blog post](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/03/10/go-static-without-losing-your-server/) did). Is it possible for this redirect to work as well when the user sends a POST request to `www.domain.com`, causing it to go to Netlify? Or would I have to change the client's code to POST to `<different_subdomain>.domain.com/legacy_slug` and migrate the POST endpoint to the different subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

Proxies (https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#proxying) accept POSTs, redirects (https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#basic-redirects) or rewrites (`HTTP 200` that transform from one path to another, both on netlify-hosted sites), no.

Kind of a subtle distinction.  So - I'd send the POST to some other path (not some other domain - just /place-we-post-to on your Netlify site, and use a proxy redirect to get to your remote service (`/place-we-post-to https://legacybackend.com 200` in `_redirects`)